# Javascript mouseover/mouseout animation working for first iteration only

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseleave, mouseout

I created a javascript animation to move a picture to the right when on mouseover and to go back to its resting position when the mouse exits the image.  It works flawlessly for the first image but when I try the other iterations the first image moves instead of the one I hover on.

*Here is the HTML code:*

```
        <div class="sectionJoueur">

            <div class="scroller">

                <figure id="infos" class="nomPositionCourt A">
                    <img src="images/infoMathieuD.png">
                </figure>

                <figure class="img">
                    <img src="images/md.jpg">   
                </figure>

            </div>

        </div>

       <div class="sectionJoueur">

            <div class="scroller">

                <figure id="infos" class="nomPositionCourt B">
                    <img src="images/infoMathieuD.png">
                </figure>

                <figure class="img">
                    <img src="images/md.jpg">   
                </figure>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="sectionJoueur">

            <div class="scroller">

                <figure id="infos" class="nomPositionCourt C">
                    <img src="images/infoMathieuD.png">
                </figure>

                <figure class="img">
                    <img src="images/md.jpg">   
                </figure>

            </div>

        </div>
```

I'm trying to use the classes names "class="nomPositionCourt A">" the target the specific image being hovered on but it doesn't seem to be working.

*Here is the JS code:*

```
    function over(){

       if ( $("#infos").hasClass("A") ){   
          $("#infos").stop().animate({"margin-left": +0});
          $(".img").mouseleave(out);
       }
       else if ( $("#infos").hasClass("B") ){
          $("#infos").stop().animate({"margin-left": +0});
          $(".img").mouseleave(out);
       }
    }

    function out(){
       $("#infos").stop().animate({"margin-left": -287});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the `id` attribute  to more than one element which suppose to be unique `id="infos"` class can be assigned to multiple elements but id should be unique

Try this one by changing the id to class

```
   $(".nomPositionCourt").hover(function(){
   if ( $(this).hasClass("A") ){   
      $(this).stop().animate({"margin-left": +0});
      $(".img").mouseleave(out);
   }
   else if ( $(this).hasClass("B") ){
      $(this).stop().animate({"margin-left": +0});
      $(".img").mouseleave(out);
   }
  },function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({"margin-left": -287});
  })
```

In `$(this)` you have the object of current hovered image

Here is the [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: There is a problem though, I have to use the second figure where the second picture is the trigger the animation because it's the only one visible when resting.  The animation starts when the mouse hover on the second picture but it's the first picture that moves, pushing the second to the right.  And I tried to change the ".nomPositionCourt" for ".img" and it doesn't work

Comment: Yes but if I simply change the id to class I will have 2 class for the same element

Comment: just remove the `id` element i have utilized `nomPositionCourt` this class in my code

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like the reason is that both of your images are using the same ID tag (which is bad practice).

This is the code I'm looking at:

figure id="infos"

You are using that same ID tag twice.  When your code runs, it's picking up the first "infos" tag it comes to, which is your first image.

Make sure to use unique ID tags and this should help resolve your problem.